# Otimização jogo Touros e Vacas

Tags: c++

Fiz esse código de um jogo chamado Bulls and Cows (touros e vacas) onde é um jogo de adivinhação, porém, é um pouco diferente, vou dar um exemplo:

Os números escondidos são 1 2 3 4.

Se você colocar 1 2 6 7, você tem Dois Touros (números certos nas posições certas)

Se você colocar 3 2 4 5, você tem 3 vacas e 0 touros (vacas são números certos
nas posições erradas) de modo que 1 2 3 4 sejam 4 touros.

Quatro touros = jogo encerrado.

É um dos exercícios primários do primeiro livro do Bjarne.

Ao ponto: preciso dar uma otimizada no código, sei que há meios mais fáceis de fazer isso, não quero que otimizar seja necessariamente ter menos código, apenas algo mais simples e que não deixe de ser manutenível e fazer seu dever, alguém tem alguma ideia? (:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

int touro = 0;
int vaca = 0;
int num1 = 0;
int num2 = 0;
int num3 = 0;
int num4 = 0;
srand(time(0)); // Pega o tempo do PC para gerar a seed
int segredo[4] = {rand()%25,rand()%25,rand()%25,rand()%25};


cin >> num1 >> num2 >> num3 >> num4;

for(int x = 0; x<4; x++){
  if(num1 == segredo[x]||num2 == segredo[x]||num3 == segredo[x]||num4  ==segredo[x])  // se for o numero (Não necessariamente a ordem) vaca++
  vaca++; 

 }

int tourosVec[4] = {num1,num2,num3,num4}; 

for(int y = 0; y<4; y++){
   if(tourosVec[y] == segredo[y]) // compara exatamente números e posições
       touro++;
   }

cout << "vacas: " << vaca << endl;
cout << "touros: " << touro<<endl;

 if(touro == 4){
     cout << "Ganhou!" << endl;
     }
     return 0;
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que você pode fazer é melhorar a organização do código, não amontoe tudo e não escreva cada hora de um jeito.

Fora isto pode fazer pouca coisa, até onde entendi.

Pode transformar `num` de 1 à 4 em um *array* e quem sabe fazer um `for` interno para comparar e simplificar o `if`. Aí `tourosVec` deixaria de ser necessário (ou poderia usá-lo no lugar dessas 4 variáveis). Isto não é exatamente uma simplificação e muitos programadores achariam até que está piorando o código em algo tão curto.

Isto está mais C e pouco C++. Usar um [`vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) no lugar de um *array* me parece ser um objetivo do exercício. Aí poderia usar outros algoritmos como o `random_shuffle` ou `find`.

Comment: É porque eu não sei como eu comparo dentro de um for UM numero com o resto do vetor, normalmente da mesma forma que ele soma 1 para o comparador, também soma 1 para o que vai ser comparado.. Eu não conheço essas funções mas irei pesquisar, valeu. (: